# Git commit error from RStudio: "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: github, rstudio

I have a project in RStudio which I push to github from within RStudio. All of a sudden I get the error, "The system cannot find the path specified", when I try to commit. The working directory is correct and I haven't moved any folders - I have no idea what changed.

I'm also getting strange errors when I try to plot (Error in (function ()  : Shadow graphics device error: r error 4 (R code execution error) and I wonder if these errors are related.

Do I need to reinstall something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and setting up a new temporary directory seemed to work for me.
Try `dir.create(tempdir())`

It may be related to the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086356/launching-r-help-error-in-fileout-wt-cannot-open-the-connection) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027871/why-does-r-session-specific-temp-directory-disappear-in-long-running-r-process)(?) wrt long-running R sessions or where there are some background refreshes happening on your system.